# UNCalendarNotificationTrigger with start date

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make a reminder app and I am having a hard time trying to set a start date for my reminders. I am able to make local Notification work with the code below. With this code, I am able to get local notification every Tuesday at the time set by the user (Indicated by the "hour" and "minute").

```
    if tuesdayIsChecked == true {

        AlarmSupportFileX.tuesdaySelectedBool = true

        hour = hourDateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
        minute = minuteDateFormatter.string(from: datePicker.date)

        var dateComponents = DateComponents()
        dateComponents.weekday = 3
        dateComponents.hour = Int(hour)
        dateComponents.minute = Int(minute)

        print(dateComponents)

        let trigger = UNCalendarNotificationTrigger(dateMatching: dateComponents, repeats: true)
        let requestIdentifier = "\(randomGeneratedString)Tuesday"
        let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: requestIdentifier, content: content, trigger: trigger)

        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request, withCompletionHandler: { error in
            //Handle error

        })

    }
```

My issue is that I only want it to trigger on the Date chosen by user.
Example: If I use my code above on 12th Nov 2018 (Monday), a notification will trigger on 13th Nov 2018 (Tuesday) and all the Tuesday that follows.

Assuming user select alarm to trigger on tuesday (dateComponents.weekday = 3).If user set a notification on 12th Nov(Monday) and they selected a start date on 25th Nov(Sunday), I want it to only show the notification on 27th Nov(Tuesday) and all the Tuesday that follows. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible using only UNCalendarNotificationTrigger.

You would need to set up some sort of mechanism for the app to set up that notification the week of the Tuesday.

One way to do this could be:

1. check if the selected date is this week

-> **IF TRUE:** register notification

-> **IF FALSE:** write to UserDefaults the date.

2. In an didBecomeActive() or viewDidLoad() you could then load the date from UserDefaults and check if the date is in this week, if that's the case, you register the notification.

Comment: Which means the user would need to open the app on the week of selected date?

Comment: Yes. If you want to circumvent this, you could register push notifications with fire base

Comment: Though, I think it should be fairly likely for the user to open the app in that week

Comment: Just worried if user set an Alarm on Monday morning. 
Thanks for the answer though, will follow your method.

Comment: The user only needs to open the app in one of the seven advancing days. I doubt people who haven’t used your app in 7 days will care

Comment: I see. So I will do the checking 7 days before the selected date. Got it! Now I know how to proceed. Thank you very much!